# Grid and Entry, Correct Alignment

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

[image]

How would I implement this in TkInter with Python?

Two numbers are input as the width and height, and are then saved to Mapwidth and Mapheight respectively. When the Confirm button is hit, the window closes.

Comment: and what is the problem ? show your code.

Comment: Is there any way to break the code until the "confirm" button is hit? I am getting some crazy errors.

Comment: what errors ? create new question and put all inforamtion - with full error message (Traceback).

Answer (score 0):

More or less:

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- function ---

def on_confirm():
    print('Mapwidth:', e1.get())
    print('Mapheight:', e2.get())
    root.destroy()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

l = tk.Label(root, text="Width")
l.grid(row=0, column=0)

e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

l = tk.Label(root, text="Height")
l.grid(row=1, column=0)

e2 = tk.Entry(root)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

b = tk.Button(root, text="Confirm", command=on_confirm)
b.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```